# How to move ownership of PathBuf together with Path slice

Tags: rust

I want to create a `struct` containing a `PathBuf` (with an absolute path) and a `&Path` (with a relative path derived from that absolute path).  Here is my attempt:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

struct File<'a> {
    abs_path: PathBuf,
    rel_path: &'a Path,
}

impl<'a> File<'a> {
    fn new(abs_path: PathBuf, rel_path: &'a Path) -> File<'a> {
        File { abs_path, rel_path }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let abs_path = PathBuf::from("/path/to/file");
    let rel_path = abs_path.strip_prefix("/path").unwrap();
    let _file = File::new(abs_path, rel_path);
}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `abs_path` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:17:27
   |
16 |     let rel_path = abs_path.strip_prefix("/path").unwrap();
   |                    -------- borrow of `abs_path` occurs here
17 |     let _file = File::new(abs_path, rel_path);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^  -------- borrow later used here
   |                           |
   |                           move out of `abs_path` occurs here
```

I understand that I cannot transfer ownership of `abs_path` because I borrowed a reference to it when I created `rel_path`.  I am attempting to link the two together inside the `struct`, by restricting the lifetime of `rel_path`.  Can anyone tell me how to get both values into the `struct`?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thanks.  The take-home appears to be, "Don't try to do this in the first place".  I'll consider alternative ways of solving the underlying problem.

Comment: @HuwWalters you can use `Pin` to fix the memory address, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

While there are ways to store a reference and a value together (raw pointers + `Pin`, `Box` + https://crates.io/crates/rental), the easiest thing to do would probably be to store the start and end index of the slice.

Comment: Thanks, but in the end I went with a different solution.  I'm writing a dir/ls style CLI tool, and I need to support either relative or absolute paths; and I decided to store the relative paths for display, and the absolute paths for sorting purposes.